# how to create javascript listner on server

Tags: javascript

I want to make this scenario in javascript:

I have a main html pageA that contain an iframe with child html pageB.
PageB contain js code that submit results to the server using Ajax.

is there a way to make a listener in js code of pageA that can detect if result was submitted?

could you suggest me the best way to achieve this result?

Best regards,

Comment: It's temping to close vote this as you should really provide some information on what you've tried. I've provided an answer to get you started as I appreciate it might be difficult to find a result in Google without the right keywords in this case.

Comment: You're not telling us (among many other things) if you have control over both pages and the server to which B posts. This may affect what solutions are possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about iframes but this sounds like something you could do reasonably easy using Web sockets.

Essentially a Web socket will keep a live connection to the server, such that the server can inform the client of something happening (they're often used in chat applications for example).  This differs to the usual whereby a request has to be issued from the client.

So in your example PageA could listen on a Web socket and when PageB sends a request the server then informs PageA via the Web socket.

Answer (score 0):

By using Window.postMessage API.

Please check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

If one domen, from iframe:

window.parent.bla-bla();

If different domains:

1. Change fragment location in child iframe, for exam add #exicutebla-bla()
2. Detect iframe location in parent document, if location #exicutebla-bla() execute blba-bla()

Or
Use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

```
var myForm= document.getElementById('myframeId').contentWindow
          .document.getElementById('myformid');
function detectSubmit() {
    alert("submit event fired");
}
myForm.addEventListener(myiframe , 'submit', detectSubmit, false);
```

Note this will not detect script fired submit.
Cross domain issues may arise if the iframe source is that.

Lots of assumptions here due to the questions vague nature.

Comment: Depending on your need you MIGHT monitor the "load" event of the iframe itself instead?